# Two rows using div containers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have different div containers in total number 9, they have unique styling for spacing and padding. I want to find a way now to have 2 rows, that each of these div cards will have enough spacing so that can be read easily. Currently i have one div container and below of them as new row having different spacing. I will share my logic below both css and html code.

// css code

```
.cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
}


.card img {
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
}


.card h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}



.card-container > .card {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.card-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

// bootstrap html code

```
<!-- Shop by Categories starts here -->
        <div id="hot">
          <div class="box py-4">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    Shop by Categories
                  </h2>
                  <!-- Health and Beauty icon -->
<a href="category-full.html">
  <div class="cards-container d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row flex-wrap">
            <div class="col-12">
              <img src="img/eShop-Images/NewBeauty.png.png">
              <h3>Health and Beauty</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>


  <!--Clothing & Accessories icon-->
  <a href="category-full.html">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row flex-wrap">
            <div class="col-12">
              <img src="img/eShop-Images/clothes_accessories.png.png">
              <h3>Clothing & Accessories</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>


           <!--Toys & Hobbies icon-->
                    <a href="category-right.html">
                    <div class="card-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                      <img src="img/eShop-Images/toys_hobbies.png.png">
                                        <h3>Toys & Hobbies</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
          <!--Home & appliances icon-->
                    <a href="category-full.html">
                    <div class="card-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                      <img src="img/eShop-Images/home_improvement.png.png">
                                      <h3>Home & Appliances</h3>
                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>

            
                <!-- Sport & Outdoor icon-->
                    <a href="category-right.html">
                    <div class="card-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <img src="img/eShop-Images/sport_outdoor.png.png" style="width: 56px;">
                                        <h3>Sport & Outdoor</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>

                  <!-- Computer & Tablet icon-->
                    <a href="category-right.html">
                    <div class="card-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <div  class="row flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <img src="img/eShop-Images/computers_hardware.png.png" style="width: 56px;">
                                        <h3>Computer & Tablets</h3>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  

                         <!-- Video Games icon-->
                    <a href="category-right.html">
                    <div class="card-container">
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="row flex-wrap">
                            <div class="col-12">
                              <img src="img/eShop-Images/video_games.png.png" style="width: 56px;">
                              <h3>Video Games</h3>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </a>


                   <!-- Kids and Family icon-->
                <a href="category-right.html">
                <div class="card-container">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row flex-wrap">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <img src="img/eShop-Images/kids_family.png.png" style="width: 56px;">
                          <h3>Kids & Family</h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>


              
              <!--Office equipment -->
                <a href="category.html">
                  <div class="card-container">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row flex-wrap">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <img src="img/eShop-Images/office_equipment.png.png" style="width: 56px;">
                            <h3>Office equipment</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
               
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Here your question answer in Html and CSS. It's not like your question answer, but I think it's help you. Without Bootstrap.**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Mulish:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,400&family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;700;800&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,400&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;600;700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  border: 1px solid;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 0px lightgray;
}

.card-img img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 7px 0 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 5px;
}

.card-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
  <section>
      <h1>Shop by Categories</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/04/03/11/45/water-7896610_960_720.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-text">
              <a href="#">Video Games GTA-5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img"></div>
          <div class="card-text"></div>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </section>
```